# How to efficiently handle a bidding site using socket.io and nodejs with reduced server load

Tags: node.js, optimization, socket.io

In one of my website I need to show top 6 bidding products on one of the pages, where the top bid values should update without loading the page.
I need to acheive this using nodejs socket.io, hoping that data would brodcast to multiple active users that are landed on that page , may be like in a time interval of 5 minutes.
I prefer socket since I can reduce database load by broadcasting data in each 5 mins for multiple users, But I have some confusions, like if it is working correctly

I have added the server side and client side code sample below,

Nodejs Socket.io server side code.

```
  let openConn = []; // For storing User sockets and product Id's on top bidding page

  io.on('connection', async function(socket) {

    openConn.push({socketId: socket.id, products : [] });
    socket.on("userInit",data=>{
        objIndex = openConn.findIndex((obj => obj.socketId == socket.id));
        if(typeof openConn[objIndex] !== "undefined")
          openConn[objIndex].data = data.data;
    })

    //Sample Data in openConnection of two different users in some time iterval
    //ie socket is open but not closed
    /* openConn =[
    {
      socketId : "ojIckSD2jqNzOqIrAGzL",
      products:[1234,1235,1236,1237,1238,1239]
    },
    {
      socketId : "pjsckSD2jqNzOqIrAG6L",
      products:[1234,1235,1236,1237,1238,1230]
    }
    ];*/


    setInterval(() => {
      let pageIds = [];
      openConn.forEach(item => {
         pageIds.push(item);
       });
       let topBids = queryItems(pageIds);//I am not adding this , sonce it is out of scopre , It will return data for pdt pageIds
       // It will be a total of 7 different products as second users product have only 1 id of pdt as different

       socket.on("sendAllBids",async function(data, callback){
          callback(topBids);
       })


    }, 10000); // THis is the time interval sample



    socket.on("disconnect",async () =>{
      openConn = openConn.filter((user) => user.socketId != socket.id);
    });

  });
```

Client side code is given below

```
  var sock = io.connect("https://mysocketserver.com/", {upgrade: false});

  sock.emit("userInit", {
    data: listArr // list of pdtIds
  }, function(data) {

  });

  sock.emit("sendAllBids", {}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);// All bids from server
  });
```

Can someone help me to give an optimised solution as  the setInterval work for every n client, I need to execute the server side code only once and broadcast result to all n connected clients

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your question and code is confusing, missing few parts.

If you want to send data from database to all clients every 5sec then do this

```
const io = new Server(/* ... */)

io.on('connection', (/* ... */) => {
  //...
})

// main part
setInterval(async () => {
  try {

    const topBids = await topBids()
    io.of('/').emit('topBids', topBids)

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}, 5 * 60 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let topBids = [];

io.on('connection', async function(socket) {
    socket.on("userInit",data=>{
        objIndex = openConn.findIndex((obj => obj.socketId == socket.id));
        if(typeof openConn[objIndex] !== "undefined")
            openConn[objIndex].data = data.data;
    });

    socket.on("disconnect",async () =>{
        openConn = openConn.filter((user) => user.socketId != socket.id);
    });
});

setInterval(() => {
    topBids = queryItems(pageIds);
    io.emit('sendAllBids', { data: topBids });
}, 10000);
```